# Backbone-Event: add array of models to collection

Tags: backbone.js

If I add an array of models to a collection, is backbone calling callback for each model inside of this array an add-event?
I was wandering, because my view, listening to add-events of this collection, get's rendered that often, although I'm just adding one array of models to the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes [look at the documentation.](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add)

Comment: 'Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection, firing an "add" event'. Doesn't say exactely that it's firing more often if its an array.